# nagios check_http HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket, works fine from command line

Tags: nagios

I have the following service definition:

```
define service{
    use                     my-service      ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               dra
    service_description     https://www.example.com
    check_command           check_http!-I my.ip.address --ssl -H www.example.com
    notifications_enabled   1
    retry_check_interval    2
    normal_check_interval   5
    contact_groups          myadmins
}
```

The service check keeps failing with

```
Name or service not known
HTTP CRITICAL - Unable to open TCP socket
```

However, if I run http_check from the command line, I get a 200 OK result:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -I my.ip.address --ssl -H www.example.com -v

.....
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 9176 bytes in 0.074 second response time |time=0.073543s;;;0.000000 size=9176B;;;0
```

Note also that the URL in question works just fine from a browser, the certificate is valid, etc.  I also use the exact same service definition for a bunch of other sites, and they all work fine.  The only thing I can think of is that this remote host is running on DigitalOcean and has a "Floating IP" assigned to it.  I tried replacing `my.ip.address` above (and also in the host definition of the nagios config file) with either the Floating IP or the "standard" IP assigned to the host, and it makes no difference.

How is it possible that the same command would fail when run by nagios, but succeed when run manually?

Comment: Edit:  I'm starting to think that this may be due to having cloudflare handle the A records for www.example.com.

Comment: I have a similar case of a failing `check_http` command. Here `www.example.com` is a CNAME pointing to `*.apps.example.com` --- maybe the `*` is confusing the DNS resolver used by the plugin command?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:  don't use `check_http`, use

1. use `check_https_hostname`, and
2. make sure that the `host_name` stanza is the actual hostname
3. which requires matching the `host_name` stanzas in all the `service` and `host` definitions in the same cfg file.

So:

```
define service{
    use                     my-service         ; Name of service template to use
    host_name               www.example.com
    service_description     https://www.example.com
    check_command           check_https_hostname
    notifications_enabled   1
    retry_check_interval    2
    normal_check_interval   5
    contact_groups          myadmins
}
```

Here is why:  it becomes clear by looking at the definitions of `check_http` and `check_https_hostname` which are in the `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg` file in my installation.

```
# 'check_http' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_http
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -I '$HOSTADDRESS$' '$ARG1$'
        }

# 'check_https_hostname' command definition
define command{
        command_name    check_https_hostname
        command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http --ssl -H '$HOSTNAME$' -I '$HOSTADDRESS$' '$ARG1$'
        }
```

You will notice that the `-H` and `-I` arguments in `check_http` get the same value `$HOSTADDRESS$`, while in `check_https_hostname` they get `$HOSTNAME$` and `$HOSTADDRESS$`, respectively.

The fact that I built my original command as `check_http!-I my.ip.address --ssl -H www.example.com` did not really matter.  In the end, the `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http` command got two values for `-I` and two for `-H`, and the second pair was being ignored.

This did break "thanks" to Cloudflare, because the IP address dynamically assigned by Cloudflare to my www.example.com was not the same as the actual host IP address that I had specified in my host definition.

Finally, I wanted to mention that what helped me figure this out was setting

```
debug_level=-1
debug_verbosity=1
```

in my `/etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg` file and then looking through `/var/log/nagios3/nagios.debug`.

Also, check out all the different variants of the `check_http` commands in `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/http.cfg`.  There are some very useful ones.